# Naming Convention For Powers, Roots and Logarithms

Tags: logarithms, roots, exponentiation, math-history

**;TDLR**
How is the number marked as $b$ called in the following expression
$log_ab$ called?

**Background**

1. $a^b = c$ where $a$ is the base, $b$ is the exponent and $c$ is the power.
2. $\sqrt[a]{b} = c$ where $b$ is the radicand, $a$ is the index and $c$ is the root/radical.
3. $\log_ab = c$ where $a$ is the base, $b$ is the **???** and $c$ is the logarithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never heard a more formal term, but in general such numbers are the *argument* of the function. Similarly, $\ln(e^2)$ has an argument of $e^2$, etc.

Comment: That is a valid point, since any of mentioned by me can be revered as binary functions, however, I wonder that if we were to name it. Would we give it a name such as **logarithmand** (which might make sense if we look at the root case, but it doesn't sound good). OTOH we could refer to it as power because that it what it corresponds to.

Comment: Well, names are subjective, but in my experience as a teacher and as a graduate student, "argument" is the term. Others may exist. I don't claim it's the only one!

Comment: BTW, welcome to the site. I've seen a few of your posts and think you are going to be a great addition to the community!

Comment: I think you convinced me to stick to the *argument*. Thank you again for the warm welcome. :) I hope to answer some questions.

Comment: @MaciejCaputa You're very welcome. BTW, if you're happy with the answer, please accept it so that it doesn't add to the "unanswered" queue. No pressure, though. You don't have to!